# Change Chinese Samsung Note 5 Duo to English

Tags: samsung

I bought a brand new Samsung Note 5 Duo from Taiwan. Of course it is all in Chinese, but I was hoping to be able to change the language to English. The problem is that I wasn't able yet to get to the home screen with the icons to choose Settings. The startup screen seems to take me to wireless setup (I don't have any SIM cards installed yet but have an active wireless connection, which it immediately recognizes, but I want to work offline for now and disconnected). How can I get to the setup icon if all instructions and lists are in Chinese?

And I am wondering now whether a Chinese version will really be able to make everything in English, including the build-in applications. I may have to return it afterall. But it is such a beautiful phone. Does anybody know the impact of just changing the language to English? Will I really be able to use it properly?

Answer (score 1):

A Chinese speaking person helped me and the answer was real simple:
The first screen that appears when you turn on your phone (Welcome Page) has a Chinese word highlighted and a forward arrow. Scroll the word highlighted down to the desired language :-) and click arrow. Everything turned into English immediately and you can continue configuring from there.